# rfcomm bluetooth permission denied error raspberry pi

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi

I'm using a bluetooth dongle to try and send information from ubuntu 15.04 to raspberry pi b+ running the latest debian jessie image. I'm just following the http://people.csail.mit.edu/albert/bluez-intro/ tutorial. I got the simple RFCOMM and L2CAP protocols working. I'm having trouble running the SDP protocol. The server code is -

```
from bluetooth import *

server_sock = BluetoothSocket(RFCOMM)
server_sock.bind(("", PORT_ANY))
server_sock.listen(1)

advertise_service(server_sock, "SampleServer",service_classes=[SERIAL_PORT_CLASS], profiles=[SERIAL_PORT_PROFILE])

client_sock, client_info = server_sock.accept()

print "connection from: ", client_info

client_sock.send("PyBluez server says Hello!")
data = client_sock.recv(1024)
print "received: ", data

client_sock.close()
server_sock.close()
```

The error I'm getting is -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rfcomm-server.py", line 7, in <module>
    advertise_service(server_sock, "SampleServer",service_classes=[SERIAL_PORT_CLASS], profiles=[SERIAL_PORT_PROFILE])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bluetooth/bluez.py", line 176, in advertise_service
    raise BluetoothError (str (e))
bluetooth.btcommon.BluetoothError: (13, 'Permission denied')
```

Here are some steps I have taken-

```
Add the user 'pi' to lp group
run piscan on hciconfig hci0
Add --compat option to bluetoothd in bluetooth.service
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried running as root?

Comment: I should hit myself on the head. Sometimes the solution is that simple!

Comment: Running as root will not work if the `pip` install is local to user. The simplest way to solve this is `sudo chmod o+rw /var/run/sdp`. And from here, improve it accordingly. No huzz fuzz. This is the direct solution.

Answer (score 19):

Running your script as root kinda works, but [it's not a good practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52268/why-is-it-a-bad-idea-to-run-as-root).

According to [this thread](https://github.com/ev3dev/ev3dev/issues/274#issuecomment-74593671), you just need to adjust permissions to the `/var/run/sdp` file (which is created when using the `--compat` switch).

So, to prevent link rot I'm reproducing dlech's post and adapting it to Raspberry Pi:

1. make sure your `pi` user is in the `bluetooth` group:

   ```
   $ cat /etc/group | grep bluetooth
   bluetooth:x:113:pi
   ```

   1.1. If it's not, add `pi` to `bluetooth` group:

   ```
   $ sudo usermod -G bluetooth -a pi
   ```
2. Change group of the `/var/run/sdp` file:

   ```
   $ sudo chgrp bluetooth /var/run/sdp
   ```
3. To make the change persistent after reboot:

   3.1. Create file `/etc/systemd/system/var-run-sdp.path` with the following content:

   ```
   [Unit]
   Descrption=Monitor /var/run/sdp

   [Install]
   WantedBy=bluetooth.service

   [Path]
   PathExists=/var/run/sdp
   Unit=var-run-sdp.service
   ```

   3.2. And another file, `/etc/systemd/system/var-run-sdp.service`:

   ```
   [Unit]
   Description=Set permission of /var/run/sdp

   [Install]
   RequiredBy=var-run-sdp.path

   [Service]
   Type=simple
   ExecStart=/bin/chgrp bluetooth /var/run/sdp
   ```

   3.3. Finally, start it all up:

   ```
   sudo systemctl daemon-reload
   sudo systemctl enable var-run-sdp.path
   sudo systemctl enable var-run-sdp.service
   sudo systemctl start var-run-sdp.path
   ```

Credit goes to user [dlech](https://github.com/dlech) who "figured it out" originally.

Comment: You need to modify the service file to include: `ExecStartPost=/bin/chmod 662 /var/run/sdp`. This worked for me

Comment: Do i add this as 3rd line to the `[Service]`?

Answer (score 2):

This solution worked for me:

```
sudo chmod o+rw /var/run/sdp
```

Thanks @eigenfield

Answer (score -3):

And `sudo` does the job.

```
sudo python script.py
```