# bluetooth.btcommon.BluetoothError: (2, 'No such file or directory')

Tags: bluetooth

I'm simply trying to run the RFCOMM server example at https://code.google.com/p/pybluez/source/browse/trunk/examples/simple/rfcomm-server.py

```
$ python2 rfcomm-server.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rfcomm-server.py", line 20, in <module>
    profiles = [ SERIAL_PORT_PROFILE ],
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bluetooth/bluez.py", line 176, in advertise_service
    raise BluetoothError (str (e))
bluetooth.btcommon.BluetoothError: (2, 'No such file or directory')
```

I am getting this error. My code is working on windows but I could not work Ubuntu 15.10.

Comment: Did you done multiple installations of BlueZ package ?

Answer (score 21):

I had the same problem on Raspbian, and solved by:

- Running bluetooth in compatibility mode,

  by modifying `/etc/systemd/system/dbus-org.bluez.service`,

  changing

  `ExecStart=/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd`

  into

  `ExecStart=/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd -C`
- Then adding the Serial Port Profile, executing: 
  `sudo sdptool add SP`

References:

- https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=133263
- https://github.com/karulis/pybluez/issues/161
- https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/41776/failed-to-connect-to-sdp-server-on-ffffff000000-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: Make sure you run the following after doing this:  1. systemctl daemon-reload  2. service bluetooth restart

Comment: The example `rfcomm-server.py` is already acting as the serial port application so there is no more need to do `sudo sdptool add SP`.

Comment: This helped, but in my case I also had to run my Python script as superuser.

Answer (score 9):

I ran the same problem even after @GozzoMan's solution because `/var/run/sdp` file was not being generated at all after calling `sudo sdptool add SP`. The problem was **the location of daemon service file was different** on my system (Raspbian Buster on Raspberry Pi).

If you experience the same;

- Check the status of bluetooth daemon and look for the service file
  path (2nd line)

```
sudo service bluetooth status

# alternative: 
# sudo systemctl status bluetooth
```

In my case the service file was run at `/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service`, NOT FROM `/etc/systemd/system/dbus-org.bluez.service`.

[image: bluetooth service status]

- Then modify the correct file (which was
  `/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service` in my case) to add `-C` to
  the `ExecStart=/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd` line as instructed in
  the previous answer.
- Do not forget to reload daemons and restart bluetooth service before running sdptool:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart bluetooth

sudo sdptool add SP
```

Now `/var/run/sdp` should be generated.

**Note:** If you experience permission errors, check the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42306883/4406572

Answer (score 7):

The answer about editing the service file works, but breaks on every update.

The correct way is to add an override to the file

> /etc/systemd/system/bluetooth.service.d/override.conf

with the following content:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd -C
```

The first line clears the existing ExecStart, the second line adds the correct one.

You will have to create the directory.

Comment: I tested this method in Ubuntu, it works. The `override.conf` file does indeed did an override. And I can see `/var/run/sdp` socket file auto-created after reboot.

Comment: this works in ubuntu on raspberry pi but I need to do it this way on debian bullseye https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/41776/failed-to-connect-to-sdp-server-on-ffffff000000-no-such-file-or-directory